# Is the following exercise solved correctly? (Metric Spaces)

Tags: metric-spaces

I am learning metric spaces on my own and this is a question from Metric Spaces - Mícheál O'Searcoid, Exercises 1.2.

**Suppose that $d$ is a metric on set $X$. Prove that the inequality $|d(x,y)-d(z,w)|\leq d(x,z)+d(y,w)$ holds for all $w,x,y,z\in X$.**

My attempt:

Since $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ and $d(z,w)\leq d(z,y)+d(y,w)$.

Hence, $|d(x,y)-d(z,w)|\leq |d(x,z)-d(y,w)|\leq d(x,z)+d(y,w)$

But my problem with it is I think I am just "fitting" my solution to the final form. 
Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Many thanks to both of you for answering. I think I will require more time to think about this before changing the accepted answer. I recognize the mistake pointed out by @JordanGreen. I hope this isn't a problem and please don't take it personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intermediate step $|d(x,y)-d(z,w)| \leq |d(x,z)-d(y,w)|$ in your argument is not correct.  As a counterexample, take $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, let $x=y = (0,0)$, let $z = (0,1)$, and let $w = (2,0)$.  Then $|d(x,y)-d(z,w)| = \sqrt{5}$, but $|d(x,z)-d(y,w)| = 1$.

One way to prove the inequality $|d(x,y)-d(z,w)| \leq d(x,z) + d(y,w)$ is as follows: we 
note that 
$$
|d(x,y)-d(z,w)|= \begin{cases} 
d(x,y)-d(z,w), & d(x,y) \geq d(z,w) \\
d(z,w) - d(x,y), & d(z,w) \geq d(x,y).
\end{cases}
$$
To prove that $|d(x,y)-d(z,w)| \leq d(x,z) + d(y,w)$ for all $x,y,z,w \in X$, it therefore suffices to show that 
$$
d(x,y)-d(z,w) \leq d(x,z) + d(y,w) \tag{1}
$$
and 
$$
d(z,w) - d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(y,w) \tag{2}
$$
both hold for all $x,y,z,w \in X$.  For (1), we use the triangle inequality twice to give
$$
\begin{split}
d(x,y) - d(z,w) &\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)-d(z,w) \\
&\leq d(x,z) + d(y,w)+d(w,z) - d(z,w) \\
&= d(x,z) + d(y,w).
\end{split}
$$
Here, we have made use of the reflexive property of $d$ ($d(a,b) = d(b,a)$) without commenting inline.)
Similarly, to prove (2), write
$$
\begin{split}
d(z,w)-d(x,y) &\leq d(w,y) + d(y,z)-d(x,y) \\
&\leq d(w,y)+d(y,x) + d(x,z) - d(x,y) \\
&=d(y,w) + d(x,z).
\end{split}
$$
Actually, a separate proof of (2) can be evited if one merely relabels (1) to reverse the roles of $x$ and $y$ and then to reverse the roles of $z$ and $w$.  (One can do this because if (1) holds for all $x,y,z,w$ and we want to show it holds for -say- a fixed $(x_0, y_0, z_0, w_0)$, then one can take $x=y_0$, $y=x_0$, $w=z_0$ and $z=w_0$.)